# iOS device settings: Is it possible to setup wifi and prevent user from changing it?

Tags: ios, swift, network-programming, wifi

**Goal:** 
I want to create app (with Swift) where user set his admin passcode and setup wifi settings (SSID, wifi password) which can not be changed from general settings on his device but only by using my app after entering admin passcode. I looked at apple documentation (SystemConfiguration) without success. I can distribute it Ad-hoc without submitting app for review.

**Why I need it?**
My customer have application on iPad device which is not working on newer iOS versions and have configured wifi router with specific network traffic restrictions for preventing access to apple update servers. Problem is when someone changes wifi settings and connect to another network without those restrictions. He will see update reminder every day and probably he will install that update and application stops working.
Jailbreak is not solution. I can not edit or update this installed application he has on iPads.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to setup iOS (9.1) device wifi settings (network it is connected to)?
2. Is it possible to prevent user from changing wifi
       settings in general settings on his device?

Comment: I can't give you a source so i'm not answering, but I can assure you that it is not possible. Apple ecosystem is strictly controlling apps, you can't change anything system-wide without user being able to change it, even if he gives consent to it.

Comment: Thank you, that is sad. I tried to contact apple support but their answers were vague, they told me to first send them my app for review and then we could talk about it, but I wanted to be sure that I am able to do it before I start.